# what is the difference between slash backslash,hyphen in date field?

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime

why it is giving three different results?

```js
var hyphen=new Date('2014-04-03').toUTCString();

var slash=new Date('2014/04/03').toUTCString();

var backslash=new Date('2014\04\03').toUTCString();


console.log('hyphen=      '+hyphen+ '\n' +'slash=       '+slash+ '\n' + 'backslash=   '+backslash);
```

Answer (score 2):

[MDN: Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

Beside that a `\0` is a `null` character, so `'2014\04\03'` equals `'2014_4_3'`, where `_` is a null character. The result of parsing a string containing null characters as date is not defined at all.

Comment: so we should only use hyphen ?

Comment: @Mahi—no, you should only use one of the formats supported by [ECMA-262](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.parse).